# How to put button in bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar element in my html website and was wondering how I can add a button to the navbar. I wanted to do this because I want to call a js function to switch the content of a page, instead of having the browser load a whole new page. I have tried putting a button in, but it doesn't have the correct formating. I just want it to look like the normal link in the navbar, but call a function and not a link.

```
<!--Nav bar source-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a>button needed here</a></li>
                <li><a>button needed here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!--script.js source-->
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.page1 = true; //whether to show page1 or not
    $scope.page2 = false;
}]);
```

EDIT:
It doesn't have to be a button, I was just hoping for a solution to this problem

Comment: Why does it have to be a `button`? You can just add another link and when the user clicks that unique `className`, execute the code.

Comment: @Quoid If there's only one element, it's probably better to give it an `id` instead of using the `class` to select it.

Comment: If you are using `angularJS` (*as in you will be adding/modifying angular code*) make sure to add it as a tag. For your problem you can just do `preventDefault` or `return false` on the event handler for the `<a>` tag, then call the function you want.

Comment: @Mike either works; the point I was making was, why does the element have to be a `button`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the 'ng-click' directive to the 'a' element with a function to change the page's contents. I also added 'href="#"' to the 'a' element, so the correct cursor show up on hover.

Comment: Make sure to make the onClick function `return false` to prevent the browser from navigating to the new URL